# How to use 2 databases that relate to each other

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 databases (db1, db2) - SQL Server.
And each database use another in stored procedures, functions

in db1:

```
select * from db2.dbo.users
```

in db2:

```
select * from db1.dbo.items
```

The problem is that there is hard coded db names in procedures.
Now we want to add databases db1_test, db2_test on this server.

What is the easiest way to resolve this problem without updating all procedures, functions with new database names.

Thanks!

Comment: Without updating is not possible in the same server same instance. But you can update very quickly. First create a script of all the stored procedures and functions and views to a new query window. Then find(db1.) and replace(db1_test.) using **Find and Replace** (ctrl+F). Next apply the script to the new database(db1_test). Do the same thing for db2_test as well.

Comment: There are no ways to create alias for database.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it on a separate instance or server.  Test and prod database shouldn't reside on the same box.. let alone same database.  In an ideal world that is.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But databases are devs for now. Both.

Comment: "for now"? always try to develop as if it's going into production.  will save you headache in the future.  especially if it's not too much trouble.